# Android redirection (return code 302) handling

Tags: java, android, httpclient, http-post

I am using HttpClient to do Post request to a server URL. The server URL is redirecting me and seems like my HttpClient is getting redirected automatically. I wanted to intercept the redirect response 302. I am unable to use setFollowRedirects(false). I wanted to know if there is anyway to do intercept the 302 response and stop Auto redirection?? I saw that we can achieve this using HttpURL Connection

```
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   connection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

However I want to use HttpClient and HttpPost to avoid huge changes in my current implementation. Is there any way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResponseHandler.handleResponse(HttpResponse response)` is part of the `HttpClient` class.

Also most of the `HttpClient.execute` methods return an `HttpResponse`.  Use `HttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`.

Also look at `org.apache.http.client.RedirectHandler`.

Comment: An implementation of org.apache.http.client.RedirectHandler can be found at [Jakarta commons Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/redirects.html).